# Variable allocation of memory for void* in a struct

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to allocate some memory for a struct which has a variable payload functionality.

```
typedef struct
{
const uint8_t  item_id;
const uint8_t  reserved;  
const uint16_t num_bytes;
void           *data;

} ipc_transport_item_t;

Payload:

typedef struct
{
uint32_t timestamp_value;
} ipc_transport_sync_packet_t;

ipc_transport_item_t *test = (ipc_transport_item_t*)malloc(8);

ipc_transport_sync_packet_t *mypacket = (ipc_transport_sync_packet_t *)(test->data);
```

Here void data is where I want my variable payload to start. So while allocating memory I am allocating memory for 4bytes (other fields ) plus my payload is 4 bytes. So i am allocating total of 8 bytes. But when I try to access the data by casting it to my payload struct to enter information there I am not able to do that. Am I missing something here?

Should I be allocating ipc_transport_item_t first and allocate seperate memory for data depending on what I want to use payload for? And then point the allocated payload to ipc_transport_item_t.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want here is a *flexible array member*:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t  item_id;
    uint8_t  reserved;  
    uint16_t num_bytes;
    uint8_t  data[];
} ipc_transport_item_t;
```

This allows you to allocate an arbitrary amount of bytes for the `data` array.  You would then allocate the space as follows:

```
ipc_transport_item_t *test = malloc(sizeof(ipc_transport_item_t) + 4);
```

Note also that the `const` qualifier has been removed from the members, as otherwise you would be unable to give them a value.

Comment: I would rather `malloc(sizeof(*test) + 4 * sizeof(text -> data[0]))`

Comment: Thank you I tried it out and works for me.